# Why does Android webview show "Next" in keyboard only if type="number" and not with type="text"?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a form with a few input fields. So I want to navigate between the fields with the next button but that just works when the input field type is "number". With type="text" it doesn't!

Is this a bug in Android 3.2.1?

My input fields are like that:

```
<input type="text" name="..." .... /> --> keyboard "Go"
<input type="text" name="..." .... /> --> keyboard "Go"
<input type="number" name="..." .... /> --> here it shows the "Next" button on the keyboard
<input type="text" name="..." .... /> --> keyboard "Go"
```

Answer (score 2):

DennisA is right for Android 4.0 and below.

In short this is not a bug but sadly how google implemented it (I would prefer a consistent GO for all those keys so you can prevent the default action in JavaScript).

With Android 4.1 (JellyBean), you can change the default behavior by extending WebViewInputConnection:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewClassic.java#L379

(hackery involved)

Comment: I'm unclear on how to make this work. Both WebViewInputConnection and the necessary input WebViewCore.TextFieldInitData seem to be out of reach. Do you have an example of how you did this? Thanks.

Comment: that link is dead now; ITYM https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/jb-release/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewClassic.java#L362 
but the fact that it's dead makes me doubt it'll work in 4.2 :/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to specify that your input is not a multiline input, otherwise, the next  is replaced by next

Comment: I put an example in my question.

Answer (score 0):

When webkit renders those input fields, it converts them into a class called android.webkit.WebTextView which determines how the softkeyboard would look like and there doesn't seem to be any good way to override the ImeOptions set by the WebTextView class